# Node.JS race condition in array manipulation

Tags: arrays, node.js, race-condition

Is it possible to encounter race condition in Node.JS if I am for example adding element to array and filtering that array at the same time?

Example:

I am pushing something to array while filter is running...

Is there a chance element will not be added?

Comment: `arr.filter` and `arr.push` is sync. so you can't get race conditions.

Comment: Node is single threaded (and runs to completion). Filter does not modify the original array. So where would the push fail?

Comment: Thank you guys! 

I am creating distributed system and got a little confused...